# Does voting for closure tags the question as well?

Tags: support

I noticed that a question lined up in the review queue is marked with 'this question has been flagged as being... (too broad, off-topic etc)'.

A few questions I have:

1) Does a question automatically gets flagged when I vote (for the first time) for closure?

2) Does a voted-for-closure question pops up in the queue of other users when not manually flagged?

3) And related: do I have to vote for closure and flag it as well when I vote to close as a first voter or is voting sufficient to open up the queue for others to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order:

1. No I don't think so. Flagging is separate from the queue for closure, and directly alerts moderators.
2. Yes, all questions that recieve close votes show up in the queue for closure.
3. No, vote to close is enough. As I see it, when you have the vote-to-close privilege, flags are only needed for more serious problems when you need to alert moderators. Examples could be spam, offensive content or material of extremely low quality, that is, stuff that should be deleted as soon as possible. However, before you get the vote-to-close privilege flags can be used in the same way as close votes, i.e. to indicate Qs that are duplicates, too broad etc.

Answer (score 2):

When questions are marked for closure, you have to enter a reason for doing so. The problem is that there are not many reasons, so you often have to use one of the very broad ones - unclear what you are asking or too broad. The same is true for the badly researched (if any) questions, where the homework tag fits best. I think this also answers your first question (if I understand it right).

The close-votes gets displayed in the review queue of all other users which have the right to vote until the quorum is reached. You can also see the small number next to review. Don't get confused that this number does not always disappears, even if your review queue is empty. Than the number of votes necessary has not been reached yet and other members can still vote.

When you mark a question for closure, you have to choose a reason for doing so. This reason is then also presented to the other voters (which can choose another reason as well).